# R New column representing if score is the best up to that point

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have a dataset like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
                 score = c(0, 3, 2, 3, 3))
```

I.e.,

```
   id score 
1   1   0   
2   1   3 
3   1   2
4   2   3
5   2   3
```

How could I add a new column that is a "Yes" if they're score on that row is the best (max) of all the scores up to that point in the dataset and a "No" otherwise. So, I would want it to return:

```
   id score improvement
1   1   0        No
2   1   3        Yes
3   1   2        No
4   2   3        No
5   2   3        No
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `with(df, ifelse(score==max(score), "Yes", "No"))`

Comment: If there were a 6th row with a score of 4, it would be marked as 'Yes'?

Comment: @PauloMiraMor Yes.

Comment: @akrun The problem with that is I need to do it for each group of ids.

Comment: No problem `with(df, ave(score, id, FUN = function(x) ifelse(x==max(x), "Yes", "No")))`

Comment: @akrun Wow. I think you're totally right. Give me a sec to try it.

Comment: Are you sure your expected output is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution:

```
df$improvement <- factor(ave(df$score, df$id,
                            FUN=function(i) c(Inf, head(cummax(i), -1)) < i),
                         labels=c("No", "Yes"))
```

The idea that the first observation is always "No", which is achieved through prepending Inf, and then `cummax` is used to see if there was an improvement from the previous observation.  `ave` allows this operation to occur over groups. I encase the outcome in `factor` to represent the values with yes/no labels.

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for. It will give a "Yes" if it was the max score up to that point and not only if it's the max score at any point. Thank you!

Comment: The max possible score is 12. So if someone gets a 12, there's no more room for improvement. Do you know how I could make it so that when someone gets a 12, on any subsequent rows they get NA on improvement?

Comment: I think your question in the previous comment would be worth posting as a new question. I can think of a couple of potential solutions, but they are pretty different from the solution that I have here.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `dplyr` this pretty easily.

```
library(dplyr)

 df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(max_score = ifelse(score == max(score) & min_rank(score) > 1, "Yes", "No"))

Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
Groups: id [2]

     id score max_score
  <dbl> <dbl>     <chr>
1     1     0        No
2     1     3       Yes
3     1     2        No
4     2     3        No
5     2     3        No
```

*EDIT: Fixed to match expected output.*

Answer (score 3):

Based on the expected output, perhaps this helps

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df)[, improvement := "No"
       ][, .I[uniqueN(score)>1 & score==max(score)], id]$V1
df[i1, improvement := "Yes"]
df
#    id score improvement
#1:  1     0          No
#2:  1     3         Yes
#3:  1     2          No
#4:  2     3          No
#5:  2     3          No
```

*Explanation*

The logic is not clear.  But, it seems like the OP wanted to create the 'improvment' column with "Yes" only for those 'id' having more than one 'score' and the maximum `score` among them while the 'id' for example '2' in this case have all the same 'score' so it is left as 'No'.

In the above solution, we converted the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), create an 'improvement' column with only "No" values, then get the row index (`.I`) grouped by 'id' for those having more than one `unique` 'score' (`uniqueN(score)>1`) and (`&`) where the 'score' is the maximum value (`score == max(score)`).  Using this on `i`, we assign (`:=`) the 'improvement' to "Yes"